# why am I getting form is not defined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to develop a workout app and right now I am just trying to test a button that when I click it, it adds the phrase 'this is the form', but my browser has gone blank and in the console I get this error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: form is not defined

This is my components/app.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import AppActions from '../actions/AppActions';
import AddForm from './AddForm.js';

export default class App extends React.Component {

    render(){

        return(
            <div>
                <h1 className="text-center page-header">WorkoutLogger</h1>
                <a onClick={AppActions.showForm.bind(null, 'this is the form')} href="#" className="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add Workout</a>
                <br />
                {form}
                <br />
                WORKOUTS
                <br />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This is my components/AddForm.js file:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class AddForm extends React.Component {

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                FORM
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This is my actions/AppActions.js file:

```
import {dispatch, register} from '../dispatcher/AppDispatcher';
import AppConstants from '../constants/AppConstants';

export default {
    showForm(form){
        dispatch({
            actionType: AppConstants.SHOW_FORM, form
        })
    }
}
```

This is my dispatcher/AppDispatcher.js file:

```
import {Dispatcher} from 'flux';

const flux = new Dispatcher();

export function register(callback) {
    return flux.register(callback);
}

export function dispatch(payload){
    console.log(payload)
    flux.dispatch(payload);
}
```

This is my constants/AppConstants.js file:

```
export default {
    SHOW_FORM: 'SHOW_FORM'
}
```

This is my stores/AppStore.js file:

```
import {dispatch, register} from '../dispatcher/AppDispatcher';
import AppConstants from '../constants/AppConstants';
import {EventEmitter} from 'events';
import assign from 'object-assign';
import AppAPI from '../utils/AppAPI';

const CHANGE_EVENT = 'change';
const _showForm = false;

var _items = [];

var AppStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
    emitChange: function(){
        this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
    },
    showForm: function(){
        _showForm = true;
    }
})

AppDispatcher.register(function(payload){
    var action = payload.action;

    switch(action.actionType){
        case AppConstants.SHOW_FORM:
            AppStore.showForm();
            AppStore.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
            break;
    }

    return true;
});

module.exports = AppStore;
```

Comment: `{form}` where did you define the variable form in `components/app.js`? Is this a store variable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

{form} is not defined in your components/app.js, if you wanted to display the AddForm component in that place then replace {form} with

Comment: Sounds incomplete statement.